# How to loop number (input:5) in php

Tags: php

How to loop with sample `input = 5`

and the output :

```
1 2 3 4 5
0 2 3 4 5
0 0 3 4 5
0 0 0 4 5
0 0 0 0 5
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
$i=5; 
for($a=1; $a<=$i; $a++){ 
   echo $a." "; 
} 
echo "\n"; 
for($a=0; $a<=$i; $a++){ 
  if($a==1){ 
   continue;
  } 
  print "$a "; 
} 
echo "\n"; $ex = array(1,2); 
for($a=1; $a<=$i; $a++){ 
  if(in_array($a, $ex)){ 
    continue;
  } 
  print "$a "; 
} 
?>
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried so far?

Comment: <?php
    $i=5;
    for($a=1; $a<=$i; $a++){
        echo $a." ";
    }
    echo "\n";
    for($a=0; $a<=$i; $a++){
        if($a==1){
            continue;}
            print "$a ";
    }
    echo "\n";
    $ex = array(1,2);
    for($a=1; $a<=$i; $a++){
        if(in_array($a, $ex)){
            continue;}
            print "$a ";
    } ?>

Comment: do your homework at your home :)

Comment: I tried with above code, I want to know how write from STDIN to STDOUT

Comment: >How to solve this issue? You haven't said what the issue is

Comment: here.. sample input : 5 | sample output: 1 2 3 4 5 | 0 2 3 4 5 | 0 0 3 4 5 | 0 0 0 4 5 | 0 0 0 0 5

Comment: Think simple. In your first loop, add another loop say $b and check a condition $a > $b means 0 else echo $a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think simple

```
<?php
$input = 5;
for($i = 1; $i <= $input; $i++ ) {
    for($j = 1; $j <= $input; $j++) {
        if( $i > $j) {
            echo "0 ";
        } else {
            echo $j . " ";
         }
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Nice logical solution for the task. But it will be difficult to understand for another person in the future, what this piece of code does.

Answer (score 2):

Using built-in functions, it's easier to read and understand:

```
$input = 5;
$nums = range(1, $input);
for ($zeros_count = 0; $zeros_count < $input; $zeros_count++) {
    echo str_repeat('0 ', $zeros_count);
    echo implode(' ', array_slice($nums, $zeros_count)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But yours is more performant. If it was about crunching real data, it would become important.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer nice solution